# How to handle special characters in csv file with encoding other then utf-8

Tags: node.js, csv, character-encoding, stream

I am trying to read a csv file in nodejs using createReadStream but stuck with an issue in case of special characters. When csv file charset is UTF-8 it return special characters intact but if charset is other then UTF-8 then special characters are being converted to ?
Here is what i have tried :

```
let parseOptions = {
        headers: false,
        ignoreEmpty: false,
        trim: true,
        discardUnmappedColumns: false,
        quoteHeaders: true
    };
let stream = fs.createReadStream(obj.data.file_data.path, {encoding : 'utf8'});
let parser=csv.fromStream(stream, parseOptions)
    .on("data", function(row){
        console.log('Row data ----->', row);
        // Prints row
    }).on("end", function(){
      // proccess data here
});
```

I have tried with encoding option binary, utf16 and other as well but nothing seems to handle all characters. Is there any way we can ignore charset and get intact special characters or convert it to UTF-8 charset.

Comment: Do you know the encoding of the file or you need an autosense function? Is the file not corrupted right?

Comment: Yes, i need auto sense function bcz file can of any type

Comment: Did you tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/detect-character-encoding ? I think you should check for the file header (BOM for UTF, idk for other format what is the BOM)

Comment: That is ok, i''ll detect, any suggestion on how to handle these chars?

Comment: I need to know the charset list in order to suggest a solution

Comment: For now we can use itlin1 to utf-8,although we will have to pass it dynamically